# exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MedicalDevice setPrice:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2818cc3c0'

Tags: ios, swift

I just inherited this app and I am trying to add a few fields to a form.

I am receiving this error - it seems to be calling a setPrice method on MedicalDevice.

Now as far as I can tell, I've added price to the class that is expecting it...

```
@objc(MedicalDevice)
public class MedicalDevice: NSManagedObject {

    static let entityName = "MedicalDevice"
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<MedicalDevice> {
        return NSFetchRequest<MedicalDevice>(entityName: MedicalDevice.entityName)
    }

    convenience init(context moc: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.init(entity: NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: MedicalDevice.entityName, in: moc)!, insertInto: moc)
    }

    @NSManaged public var createdAt: Date?
    @NSManaged public var deviceID: String?
    @NSManaged public var expirationDate: Date?
    @NSManaged public var lotNumber: String?
    @NSManaged public var modelNumber: String?
    @NSManaged public var catalogNumber: String?
    @NSManaged public var deviceDescription: String?
    @NSManaged public var brandName: String?
    @NSManaged public var companyName: String?
    @NSManaged public var quantity: String?
    @NSManaged public var price: String?
    @NSManaged public var location: String?
    @NSManaged public var facilityID: String?
}
```

And addDevice works as such - this is where the exception is being thrown:

```
func addDevice(for deviceID: String, lotNumber: String, expirationDate: Date, modelNumber: String, catalogNumber: String, description: String, quantity: String, brandName: String, companyName: String, price: String, location: String, facilityID: String) {

    let medicalDevice = MedicalDevice(context: self.persistentContainer.viewContext)
    medicalDevice.createdAt = Date()
    medicalDevice.deviceID = deviceID
    medicalDevice.lotNumber = lotNumber
    medicalDevice.expirationDate = expirationDate
    medicalDevice.modelNumber = modelNumber
    medicalDevice.catalogNumber = catalogNumber
    medicalDevice.deviceDescription = description
    medicalDevice.quantity = quantity
    medicalDevice.brandName = brandName
    medicalDevice.companyName = companyName
    medicalDevice.price = price
    medicalDevice.location = location
    medicalDevice.facilityID = facilityID
    self.saveContext()
}
```

Now, I don't see any setPrice method (which makes sense, I just added it in the various fields), but I also don't see setX, with X being any of the other fields which were definitely saving beforehand.

What could be causing this? Obviously setPrice is somehow being called, somewhere (generated in some way?) and it doesn't exist, I am guessing.

Comment: Have you added `price` to your `MedicalDevice` Entity **in the data model**?

Comment: Doh, sorry, I am fairly new to Swift (I've worked on Swift applications, though not a ton of them). I think I found what you're talking about and I'm strongly guessing that'll probably fix it. Testing now.

Comment: Yep, that seemed to fix it. None of the other apps I've worked on with Swift have used data models. My apologies.

Comment: No worries. Core Data uses some dynamic features of Objective-C and even an experienced Swift programmer often forgets to touch data models.